# Using entrywise sum of boolean arrays as inclusive `or`

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to compare many *m*-by-*n* boolean numpy arrays and get an array of the same shape whose entries are `True` if the corresponding entry in at least one of the inputs is `True`.

The easiest way I've found to do this is:

```
In [5]: import numpy as np                                                      

In [6]: a = np.array([True, False, True])                                       

In [7]: b = np.array([True, True, False])                                       

In [8]: a + b                                                                   
Out[8]: array([ True,  True,  True])
```

But I can also use

```
In [11]: np.stack([a, b]).sum(axis=0) > 0                                       
Out[11]: array([ True,  True,  True])
```

Are these equivalent operations? Are there any gotchas I should be aware of? Is one method preferable to the other?

Comment: In your second example, you're building a new numpy array by calling stack.  Your are creating a temporary array containing all your array elements for what is a trivial operation.  I'd stay with `a + b` unless you're planning on doing multiple operations on `np.stack([a, b])`

Comment: It sure seems like [`np.any()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html?highlight=any#numpy.any) is more appropriate and readable here. `np.any([a, b], axis=0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.logical_or`

```
a = np.array([True, False, True])
b = np.array([True, True, False])
np.logical_or(a,b)
```

it also works for `(m,n)` arrays

```
a = np.random.rand(3,4) < 0.5
b = np.random.rand(3,4) < 0.5
print('a\n',a)
print('b\n',b)
np.logical_or(a,b)
```

Comment: For boolean arrays, you can also just use `|`. (Boolean arrays implement that as logical or.)